# How to get all columns names in spark in a nested structure that are of type string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have this schema, and I want to get all column names that have strings on it

```
  val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", IntegerType),
    StructField("nested", StructType(Array(
      StructField("value1", StringType),
      StructField("value2", StringType)
    ))),
    StructField("name", StringType)
    ))
```

I want to get

```
  Seq("nested.value1","nested.value2","name")
```

This is just an example, but it should work and multiple nested levels

Answer (score 3):

```scala
def extractNames(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap {
    field =>
      field.dataType match {
        case structType: StructType =>
          extractNames(structType).map(field.name + "." + _)
        case _: StringType =>
          field.name :: Nil
        case _ =>
          Nil
      }
  }
}
```

Test case:

```scala
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType),
  StructField("nested", StructType(Array(
    StructField("value1", StringType),
    StructField("value2", StringType),
    StructField("struct", StructType(Array(
      StructField("value1", IntegerType),
      StructField("value2", StringType)
    )))
  ))),
  StructField("name", StringType)
))

val names = extractNames(schema)
println(names.mkString(", "))
```

Output:

```
nested.value1, nested.value2, nested.struct.value2, name
```

Comment: Does this work on strings inside an array of struct?

```
root
|-- musics: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- music_name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- genre: string (nullable = true)
```

I have this and it's not working for the strings inside musics

Comment: How do you think we should output the nested names if it's a string field nested inside an array? Like musics.music_name and musics.time? This will cause troubles later on when you want to consume it, because you cannot differentiate whether "musics" is an array type or a struct type.

Comment: That makes sense, what I was trying to do is apply an UDF on all strings that exist on the schema

Answer (score 1):

For example, this could be done as following code:

```scala
def getName(f: StructField, prefix: String = ""): Seq[String] = {
  val newPrefixOrName = if (prefix.isEmpty) f.name else s"$prefix.${f.name}"
  f.dataType match {
    case StructType(fields) =>
      fields.flatMap(x => getName(x, newPrefixOrName))
    case StringType =>
      Seq(newPrefixOrName)
    case _ => Nil
  }
}

def getNames(s: StructType): Seq[String] = s.fields.flatMap { f => getName(f) }
```

This code goes over the the array of the fields and if the specific value is of `StructType`, then it iterates over its fields.  This code should work for deeply nested structs as well.

Comment: Does this work on strings inside an array of struct?