# Create a new column in a dataset using a case class structure

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Assuming the following schema for a table - **Places**:

```
root
|-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- street_address: string (nullable = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
|-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
|-- country: string (nullable = true)
|-- neighborhood: string (nullable = true)
```

`val places` is of type `Dataset[Row]`

and I have the following case class:

```
case class csm(
    city: Option[String] = None,
    stateProvince: Option[String] = None,
    country: Option[String] = None
)
```

How would I go about altering or creating a new data set that has the following schema

```
root
|-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- street_address: string (nullable = true)
|-- subpremise: string (nullable = true)
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
|-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
|-- country: string (nullable = true)
|-- neighborhood: string (nullable = true)
|-- csm: struct (nullable = true)
|   |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|   |-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
|   |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

I've been looking into `withColumn` methods and they seem to require UDFs, the challenge here being that I have to manually specify the columns which will be easy for this use case, but as my problem scales it will be difficult to manually maintain them

Used this as a reference: https://intellipaat.com/community/16433/how-to-add-a-new-struct-column-to-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

In your case class declaration you have `stateProvince` parameter, but in your dataframe there's `state_province` column instead.

I'm not sure if it's not a typo, so first - some quick-n-dirty not-thoroughly-tested camelCase to snake_case converter just in case:

```
def normalize(x: String): String = 
    "([a-z])([A-Z])".r replaceAllIn(x, m => s"${m.group(1)}_${m.group(2).toLowerCase}")
```

Next, let's get the parameters of a case class:

```
val case_class_params = Seq[csm]().toDF.columns
```

And with this, we can now get columns for our case class `struct`:

```
val csm_cols = case_class_params.map(x => col(normalize(x)))
val df2 = df.withColumn("csm", struct(csm_cols:_*))
+--------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
|place_id|street_address|city     |state_province|postal_code|country     |neghborhood|csm                                     |
+--------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
|123     |str_addr      |some_city|some_province |some_zip   |some_country|NA         |{some_city, some_province, some_country}|
+--------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+

root
 |-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- street_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
 |-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- neghborhood: string (nullable = true)
 |-- csm: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

**Nested case classes**

`Seq[csm]().toDF.columns` won't give you nested columns. For that some basic schema traversal is required. E.g., one way to do it, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338841/19032206):

```
def flatten(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = 
    schema.fields.flatMap {
        field =>
          field.dataType match {
            case structType: StructType =>
              flatten(structType)
            case _ =>
              field.name :: Nil
          }
        }

case class StateProvince(
    stateProvince: Option[String] = None,
    country: Option[String] = None)

case class csm(
    city: Option[String] = None,
    state: StateProvince
)

val case_class_params = flatten(Seq[csm]().toDF.schema)
// case_class_params: Seq[String] = ArraySeq(city, stateProvince, country)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but couple of questions.

I get an error saying this.
```no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)```

Also, would this solution work on nested case classes?

Comment: @Usernamenotfound, for nested classes - see the update. But as for error - have no idea. I tested it on Spark 3.1.2, where the `struct` function has this signature: ` def struct(cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*): org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. The thing is, I've just checked the docs, all the way down to Spark 2.0.2 - this function should be available and should be ok with unpacking args.

Answer (score -1):

```
case class Source(
    place_id: Option[String],
    street_address: Option[String],
    city: Option[String],
    state_province: Option[String],
    postal_code: Option[String],
    country: Option[String],
    neighborhood: Option[String]
)
case class Csm(
    city: Option[String] = None,
    stateProvince: Option[String] = None,
    country: Option[String] = None
)

case class Result(
    place_id: Option[String],
    street_address: Option[String],
    subpremise: Option[String],
    city: Option[String],
    state_province: Option[String],
    postal_code: Option[String],
    country: Option[String],
    neighborhood: Option[String],
    csm: Csm
)

import spark.implicits._

val sourceDF = Seq(
  Source(
    Some("s-1-1"),
    Some("s-1-2"),
    Some("s-1-3"),
    Some("s-1-4"),
    Some("s-1-5"),
    Some("s-1-6"),
    Some("s-1-7")
  ),
  Source(
    Some("s-2-1"),
    Some("s-2-2"),
    Some("s-2-3"),
    Some("s-2-4"),
    Some("s-2-5"),
    Some("s-2-6"),
    Some("s-2-7")
  )
).toDF()

val resultDF = sourceDF
  .map(r => {
    Result(
      Some(r.getAs[String]("place_id")),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("street_address")),
      Some("set your value"),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("city")),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("state_province")),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("postal_code")),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("country")),
      Some(r.getAs[String]("neighborhood")),
      Csm(
        Some(r.getAs[String]("city")),
        Some(r.getAs[String]("state_province")),
        Some(r.getAs[String]("country"))
      )
    )
  })
  .toDF()
resultDF.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- place_id: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- street_address: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- subpremise: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- state_province: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- postal_code: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- neighborhood: string (nullable = true)
//    |-- csm: struct (nullable = true)
//    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
//    |    |-- stateProvince: string (nullable = true)
//    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)

resultDF.show(false)

//  +--------+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
//  |place_id|street_address|subpremise    |city |state_province|postal_code|country|neighborhood|csm                  |
//  +--------+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
//  |s-1-1   |s-1-2         |set your value|s-1-3|s-1-4         |s-1-5      |s-1-6  |s-1-7       |[s-1-3, s-1-4, s-1-6]|
//  |s-2-1   |s-2-2         |set your value|s-2-3|s-2-4         |s-2-5      |s-2-6  |s-2-7       |[s-2-3, s-2-4, s-2-6]|
//  +--------+--------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I think the crucial part for the OP is: "the challenge here being that **I have to manually specify the columns** which will be easy for this use case, but as my problem scales it will be difficult to manually maintain them". I.e. OP doesn't want to manually specify columns for his case class csm.